# Keep Keyboard Focus after selecting value in Autocomplete

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, accessibility, usability

I use an Autocomplete in a Flutter Web-App (using web-renderer html, but this should not matter). There is an issue with keyboard navigation: If I flip though my UI (multiple textfields/autocompletes + a button) and select an item in an Autocomplete through the pulldown list, the focus is not returned to the textfield.

Take the following Column:

```
return Column(
    children: [
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {  },
          child: Text("Button1")
      ),
      Autocomplete<String>(
          optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
            return ["ABC", "DEF"];
          }
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {  },
        child: Text("Button2")
      )
    ]
);
```

Using TAB I navigate first to Button1, then to the Autocomplete. I select some entry by hitting Enter and then focus seems to be lost so that the next TAB starts again at Button1. This has been a complaint by some visually impaired users btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that problem once, I solved it with `fieldViewBuilder` of `Autocomplete` widget to regain focus after an option is selected. I am not sure this is a perfect solution but it worked for me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  FocusNode? _focusNode;
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Button1")),
      Autocomplete<String>(
        onSelected: (value) {
          _focusNode?.requestFocus();
        },
        fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
          _focusNode = focusNode;
          return TextField(
            key: _key,
            controller: controller,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            onSubmitted: (value) => onFieldSubmitted(),             
          );
        },
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
        return ["ABC", "DEF"];
      }),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Button2"))
    ]);
  }
}
```